# zed shaw's exercise 15 open function

Tags: python

I am a little stuck with zed shaw's exercise 15.
Actually I had no problem with the original program,
but the problem is when I try out the extra credit
where he asks us to use raw input instead of argv.

so, this is the code I used

```
filename=raw_input("enter filename :")
print "here's your file %r" % filename
txt=open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

when it asks for filename, I give the path e:\python\ex15_sample.txt
I am getting the following error in
this line --> txt = open(filename)
and it further says
no such file or directory

So, what do I do?

Comment: If you type `dir e:\python\ex15_sample.txt` on the command-line, is the file visible?

Comment: Can you try to use ` \\\` instead of `\\` when entering the filename?

Comment: Post the stack trace for your error. And your source code.

Comment: when I typed that in the command line, it shows a kind of tabular structure, where mode , last write time and length name is given. So, i think it reads the file
but i actually run the python programs using the below command
python e:\python\ex15.py

Comment: @user1297440: That's fine. I just wanted to make absolutely sure the file as typed in matched the real file exactly.

Comment: but it works fine, when I use argv instead of using raw_input

Comment: Joel Cornett, how do I find the stack trace for my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that you are using Windows you could try have to use either a `/` (forward slash) when entering a filename or use a double backslash for the path-seperator `\\`.

To enter your filename you could then try `e:/python/ex15_sample.txt` or `e:\\python\\ex15_sample.txt`.

Comment: hmm. it works okay when I use the e:\\python\\ex15_sample.txt
but when I type it like e:/python/ex15_sample.txt
then it prints 1 line from the file ex15_sample.txt
and then gives a syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: Ok that is because a ` \\` in a string normally denotes an `escape character` - but in case of the filename you actually want the normal ` \\` and you only get this when you escape the ` \\` with adding one in front of it like so ` \\\`.

Comment: okay, I understand the double slash part and the slash being an escape character, but I dont understand why it prints only 1 line and then gives a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine. You made an error when entering the filename. Check that the file really exists.

```
>>> filename=raw_input('enter filename :')
enter filename :c:\Users\All Users\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2012\RevitLookup.addin
>>> txt = open(filename)
>>> print txt.read()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<RevitAddIns>
  <AddIn Type="Application">
    <Assembly>C:\Program Files (x86)\Revit 2012 SDK\RevitLookup\CS\bin\Debug\RevitLookup.dll</Assembly>
    <ClientId>356CDA5A-E6C5-4c2f-A9EF-B3222116B8C8</ClientId>
    <FullClassName>RevitLookup.App</FullClassName>
    <Name>Revit Lookup</Name>
    <VendorId>ADSK</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>Autodesk, www.autodesk.com</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

(uh, that's just some file I happen to have lying around on my pc...)

Be sure to NOT use quotation marks when entering the file - or strip them of afterwards! Doing this for `argv` might work, but definitly not for `raw_input`.

**EDIT**: I think that's the problem: You are entering the filename with quotation marks (such as you get when you do shift-right-click "Copy As Path" in explorer). For `sys.argv`, these are removed by (Python? OS? I think Python...), but not with `raw_input`.

Comment: the file really exists and the program works when I use argv instead of raw_input

Comment: @MarceloCantos, right, I verified it myself and came to the same conclusion. Note I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by
it doesnt include the newline

Comment: @user1297440: I thought you might still have a trailing CRLF in your input read from `raw_input`, but I was wrong. Your program works fine. I have tested it also as a script run from the command line. Make sure you type the filename correctly.

Comment: @user1297440: try adding `if os.path.isfile(filename)` in your code to check file exist or not.

Comment: @user1297440:Complete code: `if os.path.isfile(filename):print "here's your file %r" % filenametxt=open(filename)print txt.read()`

Comment: but I was not entering the filename with quotation marks
I was just giving the filepath like this: 
e:\python\ex15_sample.txt

Answer (score 0):

I used the following program to finally get it work:

```
print "Type your filename:"

filename = raw_input(">")

txt = open(filename)

print txt.read()
```

I kind of puzzled why the OP used %r formatter. I didn't use it and my program still work. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.